# ElasticSearch - How perform a query using multi_match without using "dis_max"?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nosql

Is there any way to use the multi_match interface using these more complex matchs?

Obs: I believe that multi_match: best_fields works as if it were an alias pro dis_max in this situation mentioned

I am trying to use multi_match to execute some queries, but as I read in the documentation, I noticed that within the multi_match context I can not make explicit the whole complex structure of each field, for example:

```
{
    "multi_match": {
        "query":    "quick brown fox",
        "fields": [ "title", "body" ],
        "type":     "best_fields"      # default
    }
}
```

This structure above represents a simple multi_match where it was not parameterized anything besides the fields used in the match and the value of the query, if I were for example want to put zero_terms_query already could not because multi_match does not support this parameter, having as a following way:

```
{
    "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
            { "match": { "title": {
                             "query" : "quick brown fox",
                             "zero_terms_query" : 'all'
                       }} 
            },
            { "match": { "body":  "quick brown fox" }}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to do it by applying some parameters inside the own multi-match.

Comment: You've stated that you believe `best_fields` is responsible for this behavior. Did you try [any of the other available type values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types), `most_fields` for instance?

Comment: I ended up finding another solution that I believe to be the right one for the problem, the `most_fields` would be fit if it had different particularities between the fields.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multi-match-best-fields-with-complex-queries-no-dis-max/110121/2